# Changing enterprise keywords column title programatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, taxonomy, spfield, field-definition

I'm trying to rename an enterprise keywords column in a specific list of a subsite. In a Feature Activated event receiver i tried to set the column's display name by setting its title using the following method:

```
SPField field = list.Fields["Enterprise Keywords"]; 
field.Title="Test"; 
field.Update(); 
list.Update();
```

when debugging everything seems to be ok, the new name appears but when i navigate to the list, the Enterprise Keywords column is the same.

I tried using the reflection method, as suggested in a post i read, but this fails as well.

```
private static void SetFieldDisplayName(SPFieldLookup continuingProjectLookup, string displayName)
{
    Type baseType = continuingProjectLookup.GetType().BaseType;
    object obj = baseType.InvokeMember("SetFieldAttributeValue", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,    null, continuingProjectLookup, new object[] { "DisplayName", displayName });
    continuingProjectLookup.Update();
}
```

Although in debugging it seems ok, in the UI it doesnt change.

The only possible way i found to have this column renamed is if i change the site collection's Enterprise Keywords column name, but then it also changes the name to all the other lists, which i don't want to happen.

Is there no better way?

`

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to reference the [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.aspx) by it [Internal Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.internalname.aspx) or ID

> In your code there is no any guarantee that you are really modifying title for
>   Enterprise Keyword field, because Display Name is used for reference

So, below is updated code to change Enterprise Keyword field title:

```
//Rename title for Enterprise Keyword field in List
 public static void RenameEntKeywordInList(SPList list, string newTitle)
 {
     var field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("TaxKeyword");
     field.Title = newTitle;
     field.Update();
 }
```

---

There is [known issue](http://vojtan.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/displayname-of-spfield-is-not-set/) related with updating field title when the language of current Thread UI is different from language of the web

In that case use the following method:

```
private static void SetFieldDisplayName(SPField field, string displayName)
{
   var baseType = field.GetType().BaseType;
   if (baseType != null)
       baseType.InvokeMember("SetFieldAttributeValue", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, field, new object[] { "DisplayName", displayName });
   field.Update();
 }
```

Usage:

```
var field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("TaxKeyword");
SetFieldDisplayName(field, "New Enterprise Keyword Name");
```

Comment: Hey Vadim, Thanks for answering, but this method still produce the same result. When i debug everything seems to be great, once i navigate to the list - field name stays the same... :(

Comment: Hey @JohnnyT, could you please try to call Update method for field like this: field.Update(true); // propagate changes to lists that implement the field

Comment: same reaction :( if i try to change any other field in that list, it works flawlessly.. only the Enterprise Keywords field refuses to change.